# 'Globals' are not working as expected in protractor 4.0.0?

Tags: protractor

we have the following setting in our `onPrepare` function of `config` file-

```
exports.config = {

directConnect: true,
baseUrl: env.baseUrl,
capabilities: env.capabilities,

onPrepare: function () {
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
global.expect = chai.expect; // by removing this line error is not thrown
browser.manage().window().maximize();
},

setDefaultTimeout : 60 * 1000,
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
specs: [
'../Features/*.feature'
],

cucumberOpts: {
monochrome: true,
strict: true,
plugin: ["pretty"],
require: ['../StepDefinitions/*.js', '../Support/*.js'],
tags:'@AddActiveTip,@AddInActiveTip,~@AddActiveManufacturer,~@AddInActiveManufacturer'
//tags:'@TestSplitText'
}
};
```

since the upgrade to protractor 4.0, I am getting the following error and the browser hangs indefinitely and the error does not help to debug in anyway.

**error:**

```
 > protractor Config/config.js --troubleshoot

 [22:38:12] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
 [22:38:12] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
/Users/pasalar/protractor/psms-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/exitCodes.js:87
            if (e.message.indexOf(errMsg) !== -1) {
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at Function.ErrorHandler.isError (/Users/pasalar/protractor/psms-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/exitCodes.js:87:30)
at Function.ErrorHandler.parseError (/Users/pasalar/protractor/psms-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/exitCodes.js:98:26)
at process.<anonymous> (/Users/pasalar/protractor/psms-protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/launcher.js:169:54)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at process.emit (events.js:169:7)
at process.emit (/Users/pasalar/protractor/psms-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:419:21)
at process._fatalException (node.js:224:26)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

is anyone else facing this issue? are there any major changes that I am missing?

Comment: Could you please show what you have in your config set for the `framework`?

Comment: @alex nothing too fancy, added my config file. Also I am checking the global namespaces i know that some locator's were missing but should not cause this to fail . let me check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shown has nothing to do with **"globals"**, it is working as expected! my scripts were failing randomly due to network latency issues.But the error messages need to improved as the user has no idea what caused the error!

Marking it closed as I was able debug this issue!